# GoogleSheets INDEX MATCH for closest value between date range

Tags: indexing, google-sheets

in Google Sheets, I'm trying to return the account name associated with the min absolute closest value between a date range using INDEX MATCH in Excel.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(B2:B,MATCH(MIN(ABS(C2:C-$G$5)),ABS(C2:C-$G$5),(A2:A>=G2)*(A2:A<=G3))))
```

Here are the data values:

- Column A is the date range evaluated
- Column B is the name I want to retrieve
- Column C is the number which will be subtracted from the guess, to the find the smallest absolute difference.
- G5 is the guess.
- G2 and G3 are the start and stop of the date range I wanted to search between.

Here is a sample of some dummy data:

[image]

Right now the formula is working ... sorta. It is returning an account name associated with the min absolute closest value but not from the date range specified by:

```
(A2:A>=G2)*(A2:A<=G3)
```

Here is is returning account "A" as it is the first value and closest to the guess, but it is OUTSIDE of the date rage specified by G2 and G3.

The correct answer which should be returned from this example is "C", from cell B4.

What am I doing wrong with this formula?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of `match()` should be [-1, 0, or 1](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en). So basically `(A2:A>=G2)*(A2:A<=G3)` part in your formula is nothing. If you want to match between some ranges, you can use `filter()`. So your formula should be like this.

```
=arrayformula(
   index(
     filter(B2:B, A2:A >= $G$2, A2:A <= $G$3), 
     match(
       min(abs(filter(C2:C, A2:A >= $G$2, A2:A <= $G$3) - $G$5)), 
       abs(filter(C2:C, A2:A >= $G$2, A2:A <= $G$3) - $G$5), 
       0
     )
   )
 )
```

I tested it and it worked. Here is a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C0ik4JzK3NAQKrGaEGN4f3THeT3XMGed1ZpQrLPosgo/).